# SO,Basically i am doing a Timer(Stopwatch) Program in Java for 24 Hours but The hours Never Increment by one why so?

Tags: java, multithreading

Basically i am doing a Timer(Stopwatch) Program in Java for 24 Hours but The hours Never Increment by one why so?
I am not able to find out why the hours is not displaying the number of hours after each passing hour.
Here Is My Program Below:

```
public class Real
{
     public static void Th()
 {
  int hrs=0,min=0,sec=0;
  int temp=0;
     try
     {
    Thread t=Thread.currentThread();
    System.out.println(sec);
    boolean flag=false;
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t\t*****Timer*******");
    System.out.println("HOURS:MINUTES:SECONDS");
    while(flag==false)
    {
     System.out.println("\f\t\t\t\t\t\t*****Timer*******");
     System.out.println("HOURS:MINUTES:SECONDS");
     System.out.println(hrs+"\t"+min+"\t"+sec);
      t.sleep(1000);//1 sec
      sec++;     
      temp=min;
      if(sec==60)
      {
        min++;
        sec=0;           
}
if(temp==60&&sec==60)
{
  hrs++;
  temp=0;
}
if(min==59)
{
  min=0;
}
if(hrs==24||hrs==12)
{
  if(hrs==12)
  {
    hrs=0;
}
else if(hrs==25)
{
  flag=true;
}
}
}
}
catch(InterruptedException e)
{
 System.out.println("THREAD INTERRUPTED");
}
}
}
```

Comment: This is not the good way how you should implement a timer in Java, but you can make your code work if you remove `temp` variable and just perform all calculations with `min` instead. Replace `if(temp==60&&sec==60)` with `if(min==60)` and remove the next `if(min==59)`. Also, because you reset hours to zero when they reach 12, you'll never reach 25 hours, so your loop will never end.

Comment: You are better off using modulo arithmetics.

Comment: To implement a timer you should better use a [scheduler](https://www.techiedelight.com/periodically-execute-task-java/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into this bit of code:

```
if(sec==60) {
    min++;
    sec=0;           
}
if(temp==60&&sec==60) {
    hrs++;
    temp=0;
}
```

What you want is `hrs++;` to be called. In order to meet the condition in the if-statement both `temp` and `sec` need a value of 60. But `sec` cannot ever be 60 at that if-statment because it gets overridden by `sec=0;` in the if-statment above.